# MVVM Load views depending on ComboBox selected item

Tags: c#, mvvm, view, combobox, viewmodel

I am trying to dynamically load views depending on a ComboBox selected item value. I started with MVVM this week and probably I am not seeing something.

The ComboBox View is on the upper part and I want the down part view has to change depending on the selected item.

The main view looks like this:

```
   <UserControl.Resources>
    <swv:SelectSolidWorkFileTypeView x:Key="Selector" />
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type swv:SelectSolidWorkFileTypeView}"  >
        <swv:SolidWorkAssembliesFilesView />
    </DataTemplate>

    <swv:SolidWorkAssembliesFilesView x:Key="AssemblyFilesView" />
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type swv:SolidWorkAssembliesFilesView}">
        <swv:SolidWorkAssembliesFilesView />
    </DataTemplate>

    <swv:SolidWorksRotorFilesView x:Key="RotorenFilesView" />
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type swv:SolidWorksRotorFilesView}">
        <swv:SolidWorkAssembliesFilesView />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid Background="Black">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="230"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="6"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource Selector}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />

    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Content}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" />
```

I load from a List object, the values of the ComboBox

The ModelView is (what I think is relevant):

```
// Property to embed views on the main view
    object _content;
    public object Content
    {
        get { return _content; }
        set
        {
            _content = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Content");
        }
    }

    List<string> _source = new List<string> { "Assemblies", "Rotoren" };
    string _selectedItem = null;

    //property to return items to the view
    public List<string> Source { get { return _source; } }

    //property to hold the selected item
    public string SelectedItem 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return _selectedItem;
        } 
        set 
        { 
            _selectedItem = value; RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem"); 
        } 
    }
```

I have been looking on examples on how that could be made but I have had no luck, btw, I want to make it with ContentControl as shown. If anyone could give me some heads up, I would really appreciate it :)

John

**EDIT AND EXAMPLE:**

well, as Charan pointed out, I just had to use the PropertyChanged well.

As I am using the MVVM Light Toolkit, I use RisePropertyChanged. What I did was...

Setting the properties.

Here I created an event for the ComboBox as from it depends which View has to be shown and set the CurrentView Property:

```
    // cbType is a ComboBox, here is the property to it
    private string _cbType;
    public string cbType
    {
        get { return _cbType; }
        set
        {
            _cbType = value;
            if (_cbType == "Assemblies")
                //if the Type is Assemblies, it will call the proper view for it
                CurrentViewModel = new SolidWorkAssembliesFilesView();
            if (_cbType == "Rotoren")
                //if the Type is Rotoren, it will call the proper view for it
                CurrentViewModel = new SolidWorksRotorFilesView();

            RaisePropertyChanged("cbType");
        }
    }
```

And the CurrentViewModel is also a Property I created so, as it has changed, the event will be triggered and the View will be changed.

```
    //Nothing special here
    private object currentViewModel;
    public object CurrentViewModel
    {
        get { return currentViewModel; }
        set
        {
            currentViewModel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");
        }
    }
```

And in the end, you only have to bind the Property properly, in this case, the ComboBox in the View:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=cbType, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Source}" />
```

I hope it can make it clear for someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried implementing **INotifyPropertyChanged** in your viewmodel, and then raise the **PropertyChanged** event when the **SelectedItem** gets set?

If this in itself doesn't fix it, then you will be able to manually raise the **PropertyChanged** event yourself when navigating back to the page, and that should be enough to get WPF to redraw itself and show the correct selected item.

Comment: Well I have the: RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem") in my ViewModel, but when I debug, nothing seems to happen =/

Comment: Well, after learning more about MVVM, this was the answer. I was just too newbie for me to understand what INotifyPropertyChanged and PropertyChanged was. Thanks!